# Index documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I would like to index each DataFrame from each iteration in Elasticsearch.

I have the following function

```
def es_process_and_index_data(df, date):
    try:
        df_to_index = df.toPandas()
        df_to_index.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)

        # Index the DataFrame into Elasticsearch
        index_name = f"data_{date}"
        actions = [
            {
                "_op_type": "index",
                "_index": index_name,
                "_source": row.to_dict(),
            }
            for _, row in df_to_index.iterrows()
        ]
        bulk(es, actions)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error during indexing for date {date}: {str(e)}')
```

which I would like to implent here

```
step = 50
dates_to_process = [format_date(start_date + timedelta(days=x)) for x in range((end_date - start_date).days + 1)]

for i, date in enumerate(dates_to_process):
    
    details_path = f'/opt/data/mates_pbd/sahibinden_ads_details/{date}'
    try:
        df_details = spark.read.schema(details_schema).parquet(f'{details_path}/**/*.parquet')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading details data for date {date}: {str(e)}")
        continue  # Continue to the next date

    galleries_path = f'/opt/data/mates_pbd/sahibinden_galleries/{date}'
    try:
        df_galleries = spark.read.schema(galleries_schema).parquet(f'{galleries_path}/**/*.parquet')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading galleries data for date {date}: {str(e)}")
        continue  # Continue to the next date

    listings_path = f'/opt/data/mates_pbd/sahibinden_listings/{date}'
    try:
        df_listings = spark.read.schema(listings_schema).parquet(f'{listings_path}/**/*.parquet')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading listings data for date {date}: {str(e)}")
        continue  # Continue to the next date

    df1 = df_listings.limit(1000).join(df_details.limit(1000), on="external_id", how='outer')
    df2 = df1.join(df_galleries.limit(1000), on="external_id", how='outer')
    
    # es_process_and_index_data(df2, date)
    
    if i % step == 0 or i == len(dates_to_process) - 1:
        print(f'Processing date {i + 1}/{len(dates_to_process)}: {date}.')
```

The fact is that the loop itself works but when I introduce the function (which also works because I have already tested) stops working.

I have also tried to save all DataFrames each iteration in a list but Spark runs out of memory